# Searched Case works / Simple Case doesn't in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g, case-when

I have the following Searched Case field selection in a Oracle 10g `SELECT` query

```
(case 
    when LOADER_CELLS.CELL_MODE='RW' then 1
    when LOADER_CELLS.CELL_MODE='R' then 2
end) as CELL_EDIT_MODE_ID
```

but if I write it as a Simple Case expression, as follows:

```
(case LOADER_CELLS.CELL_MODE
    when 'RW' then 1
    when 'R' then 2
end) as CELL_EDIT_MODE_ID
```

I get a `ORA-12704: character set mismatch` error on the `when 'RW'` line.

I gave a look to the Oracle documentation, and it seems my syntax is correct. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: How is CELL_MODE defined?  It seems that something is incompatible between the type of the variable and the type of the constant, when used in a simple case statement.

Comment: `CELL_MODE` is `NVARCHAR2(255)`. I supposed that it could be a encoding problem but I don't know how to "cast" the constant strings to a `NVARCHAR`. Also I don't understand why Searched case does work instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I supposed that it could be a encoding problem but I don't know how to "cast" the constant strings to a NVARCHAR"

you do it with "N" syntax.

```
case LOADER_CELLS.CELL_MODE
    when n'RW' then 1
    when n'R' then 2
end
```

eg

```
SQL> select case a when 'a' then 1 end from foo;
select case a when 'a' then 1 end from foo
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12704: character set mismatch


SQL> select case a when n'a' then 1 end from foo;

CASEAWHENN'A'THEN1END
---------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in monday and let you know.